# stumped, beginner javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginning Javascript learning, and am stumped on my first function. Spelling it out for my own sake, here is what I am try to achieve:

declare variables: color and primary

set color equal to the id "color" and grab the input value

set primary equal to one of two strings based on if color's value is either red, blue, or yellow

display primary in the p with id "answer"

I don't get a output. I suspect I should be using something in place of .value, and maybe the or statement is not correct. Would someone please give me a few pointers? I would greatly appreciate it. Here is the code:

```
<div>
Color:<input id="color" />
<p>Primary Color?</p>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Click</button>
<p id="answer"></p>

<script>
function myFunction1()
{
   var color,primary;
   color=document.getElementById("color").value;
   primary=(color="red"||"blue"||"yellow")?"It is a primary color":"Not a primary color";
   document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=primary;
}
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems.

1. `=` is an assignment. `===` is a comparison. (`==` is also a comparison but does type conversion).
2. You need a complete expression on each side of your ORs

Such:

```
(color === "red" || color === "blue" || color === "yellow")
```

Alternatively, you could just search an array:

```
(["red", "blue", "yellow"].indexOf(color) !== -1)
```

Comment: Its important to note that not all browsers support `indexOf` for arrays.  However the MDN documentation supplies an add-in for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary expression must evaluate each condition using `==`, the `=` operator is used for assignment.

```
primary=(color=="red"|| color=="blue"||color=="yellow")?"It is a primary color":"Not a primary color";
```

You may also want to consider lowercasing the supplied value for a case insensitive comparison:

```
color=document.getElementById("color").value.toLowerCase();
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/K3KUK/

Comment: Consider using the `===` instead of the `==` because it's more easy to reason about?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `||` to chain values to compare, it chains conditions. You need to compare the variable to each value:

```
color == "red" || color == "blue" || color == "yellow"
```